# How do I get the last row to be automatically the last populated row

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, rows

I'd like to avoid having to set `var lastRow =3000`, how do I get the last row to be automatically the last populated row? I'm not a programmer. This is part of script to send emails from Google Sheet. I have seen other posts, but none work. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
  function sendEmails2() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2;
  var lastRow = 3000;
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, lastRow, 2);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function [getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getLastRow()) like this:

```
function LastRowMacro() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  Logger.log("Last row is: " + spreadsheet.getLastRow());
};
```

If you had a spreadsheet that looks like this:

[image: example spreadsheet]

Running the above macro would generate a log message like this:

[image: example log msg]

So in your code you would simply do this:

`var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();`

Comment: Hi, thanks for getting back so soon. This seems to work. Is there unnecessary code in here? 

`function sendEmails2() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2;
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow(); 
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, lastRow, 2);`

Comment: That depends on your definition. If you're looking for the shortest possible code then yes there is extra code that could be removed. For example the variables `startRow` and `lastRow` could be removed and you could use their values `2` and `sheet.getLastRow()` directly in the `getRange` function

Comment: Thanks for that, all makes sense. Have marked as solvved. Cheers!